# No operator "+" matches these operands, aka cannot add Array<double> to double

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, type-conversion, double

```
Array<double> times[99];
time_t start, end;
double dif;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   time(&start);
   A.insertionSort();
   time(&end);
   dif = difftime(end, start);
   times[i] = dif;
}

    double mean;
    double sum;
    double stdDev;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sum = sum + times[i];
    }
    mean = sum / 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stdDev = stdDev + pow(times[i] - mean, 2);
    }

    stdDev = sqrt(stdDev / 100);

    cout << "Mean: " << mean << endl;
    cout << "Standard deviation: " << stdDev << endl;
```

I don't understand why it's not letting me add Sum + times[index] and times[index] - mean, that's where I'm getting the error you see in the title.

A portion of my header file in case this helps:

```
#define ARRAY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Array {
public:
Array() {}                              

Array(double) {}
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? `Array` is not `double` - and why do you have an array of `Array`? This all looks very strange

Comment: Have you defined an addition operator for `Array`?

Comment: `Array<double> times[99];` looks suspicious. You basically created an array of `Array<>`objects.

Comment: Always post a complete program, not bits and pieces. See [MCVE]

Comment: You probably want either `std::array<double, 99> times;` or `double times[99];`  instead of `Array<double> times[99];`. Your `Array` template classe looks all wrong anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array<double> times[99];` is a C style array of 99 copies of `Array<double>`.

`Array<double>` seems to be a useless type.

Replace that line with `double times[99];`.

Comment: Or even better: `std::array<double, 99> times;`.

Comment: @MikeBorkland That code gots 99 problems, but std array vs C style array ain't one.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed everything. Sorry about my terrible code, only 1.5 years CSCI student so I'm pretty awful